# Show textboxes without click on Button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my settings page I have some dynamic controls i.e below:

```
<% @user_education.each do |user_edu| %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#AddSch").click(function() {
                var field = $("#field").val();
                var tb_fromEducation = "<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='ParametersFromSch' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolFrom %>' />";

                var tb_ToEducation = "<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='ParametersToSch' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolTo %>' />";


                var newRow1 = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: large; color: #212121;' >"
                + tb_fromEducation + " to " + tb_ToEducation + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size:large;color:#212121;' >"
                newRow1 += "<input type='button' class='btn_rmvsch' value='Remove'/></td></tr>";


                var input1 = "<input name='parametersSch' id='field' type='text' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolName %>' />"
                var newRow = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: x-large; color: #212121;' >" + input1 + "</td></tr>";
                $('#ControlsSch').append(newRow);
                $('#ControlsSch').append(newRow1);
            });

            $('#ControlsSch').on('click', '.btn_rmvsch', function() {
                var index = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 2
                $('#ControlsSch tr:nth-child(n+' + (index - 3) + ')').remove();
                return false;
            });


        });
    </script>
<% end %>
```

The above code creates 3 textboxes and I am getting the values from database and put it into textboxes, and it shows the value in the textboxes, below is the code of new.html.erb

```
<td align="center">
                            <table id="SchoolControls" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
                            </table>
                            <table id="ControlsSch" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
                            </table>
                            <input id="AddSch" type="button" value="Add" />
                        </td>
```

And in the above code I am using "ControlsSch" table for display dynamic controls, and the problem is that the textboxes is visible  after click on button "Add" and I want that when I go to the "settings" page the textboxes already visible without click on "Add" button. Kindly help me, waiting for reply. Thanks.

Comment: question is unclear... why not add the contents on **$(document).ready();** ?

Comment: simple is that when I am at "setings" page the dynamic controls are visible without click on "Add" buton

Comment: that's what i'm trying to tell you... just remove the click habdler and place the codes directly under $(document).ready();

Comment: @Sunny: you are possibly mis-interpreting the OP`s Question. what he wants is to create dynamic controls on click of `AddSch` but with the current code they are appearing without initiating any click event over that button `AddSch`.

Comment: @HassanAliKhan: well i think the click event is getting triggered somewhere in your code, you may need to check you complete code .

Comment: @dreamweiver: I think I got it right. OP has some code that adds few input elements on a button click. OP Want those elements to be added without doing a click, means on DOM load.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
<% @user_education.each do |user_edu| %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var field = $("#field").val();
                var tb_fromEducation = "<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='ParametersFromSch' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolFrom %>' />";

                var tb_ToEducation = "<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='ParametersToSch' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolTo %>' />";


                var newRow1 = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: large; color: #212121;' >"
                + tb_fromEducation + " to " + tb_ToEducation + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size:large;color:#212121;' >"
                newRow1 += "<input type='button' class='btn_rmvsch' value='Remove'/></td></tr>";


                var input1 = "<input name='parametersSch' id='field' type='text' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolName %>' />"
                var newRow = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: x-large; color: #212121;' >" + input1 + "</td></tr>";
                $('#ControlsSch').append(newRow);
                $('#ControlsSch').append(newRow1);


            $('#ControlsSch').on('click', '.btn_rmvsch', function() {
                var index = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 2
                $('#ControlsSch tr:nth-child(n+' + (index - 3) + ')').remove();
                return false;
            });


        });
    </script>
<% end %>
```